# Allow .oft file extension

Tags: files, media

How to allow media module to support `.oft` file extension?

Checked supported file extensions in `includes/file.mimetypes.inc`. It does not have `oft` extension listed. How can I add it without hacking core files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add mime types without hacking core files, you will want to create a new module and use the [hook_file_mimetype_mappings_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_mimetype_mapping_alter/7).
For example assuming you name your module oftmimetype then like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_file_mimetype_mapping_alter().
 */
function oftmimetype_file_mimetype_mapping_alter(&$mapping) {    
  // Add support for oft.
  $mime_type = 'application/x-font-otf';
  // If the mime type does not already exist, add it.
  if (!in_array($mime_type, $mapping['mimetypes'])) {
    $mapping['mimetypes'][] = $mime_type;
  }
  // Get the array index for that mime type and assign the extension to it.
  $mapping['extensions']['oft'] = array_search($mime_type, $mapping['mimetypes']);
  }
}
?>
```